# Unable to parse links (href) from a page via PHP

Tags: php

Please see my script below :

```
<?php

    function getContent ()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/test.php/test2.php');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $output=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;

    }

    function getHrefFromLinks ($cString){

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $dom = new DomDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($cString);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $nodes = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
        foreach($nodes as $href) {

            echo $href->nodeValue;   echo "<br />";                    // echo current attribute value
            $href->nodeValue = 'new value';              // set new attribute value
            $href->parentNode->removeAttribute('href');  // remove attribute
        }

        foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {

        }

        libxml_clear_errors();

    }



echo getHrefFromLinks (getContent());

?>
```

The output of http://localhost/test.php/test2.php is :

```
<a href='/oncelink/index.html'><span class="lsbold">Luck</span> Lucky</a><a href='/oncelink-2/lucky'locki'><span class="lsbold">Luck</span>'s Locki</a>
```

When  **echo getHrefFromLinks (getContent());** runs, the output is :

```
/oncelink/index.html<br />/oncelink-2/lucky<br />
```

This is wrong, as the output should be :

```
/oncelink/index.html<br />/oncelink-2/lucky'locki<br />
```

I understand that the href value generated from the link is somehow incorrect as it includes an additional apostrophe but I won't be able to change that as it is pre-generated.

The other question is, how can I get the value of the span tag :

```
<span class="lsbold">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can’t expect a DOM parser to get you the results you want, when you feed invalid HTML into it to begin with. Your second link would only link to `/oncelink-2/lucky` in any modern browser as well, that applies error correction as specified.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CBroe , Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Who generates that broken HTML in the first place, and why can’t they be asked to fix this? Jumping through hoops to somehow try and work with messed-up data is always the less preferable option to actually getting that data fixed to begin with ...

Comment: @CBroe the output was generated from a website in which we don't have access to, and that we currently don't have the admin access to check it. As we are required to finish this, we are thinking of using regex but can't seem to let it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED :)**

Well. If it's stupid but it works, then it aint stupid :D

Just added the following code in the end :

```
$fix = str_replace("href='", 'href="', getContent());
$fix = str_replace("'>", '">', $fix);
echo getHrefFromLinks ($fix);
```